# The instance of entity type 'Company' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am getting error below:

> The instance of entity type 'Company' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.'

Here is my context:

```cs
public class Context: DbContext
{
    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options)
    {
        this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        Seed.OnModelCreating(builder);
        //builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}
```

Repository Base

```cs
public class EfRepository<T> : IAsyncRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly Context_context;

    public EfRepository(Context dbContext)
    {
        _context = dbContext;
    }

    public virtual T GetById(int id)
    {
        var keyValues = new object[] { id };
        return _context.Set<T>().Find(keyValues);
    }


    public List<T> List(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        return filter != null ? _context.Set<T>().Where(filter).ToList() : _context.Set<T>().ToList();
    }

    public int Count(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        return filter != null ? _context.Set<T>().Where(filter).Count() : _context.Set<T>().Count();
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Update(T entity)
    {
        var model = _context.Entry(entity);
        model.State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetQueryable(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        return filter == null
            ? _context.Set<T>()
            : _context.Set<T>().Where(filter);
    }

    public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        return filter == null
            ? _context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault()
            : _context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(filter);
    }

    public T GetWithoutTracking(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        return filter == null
            ? _context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault()
            : _context.Set<T>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(filter);
    }
    public EntityState GetEntityState(T entity)
    {
        return _context.Entry(entity).State;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class CompanyRepository : EfRepository<Company>, ICompanyRepository
{
    public CompanyRepository(Context dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {}
    
    public IQueryable<CompanyDtoWithDetail> GetCompanyWithDetail(int? id = null)
    {
        return (from company in _context.Companies
                join companyType in _context.Definitions on company.CompanyTypeId equals companyType.Id
                join country in _context.Countries on company.CountryId equals country.Id
                join city in _context.Cities on company.CityId equals city.Id
                join district in _context.Districts on company.DistrictId equals district.Id
                join customerGroup in _context.Definitions on company.CustomerGroupId equals customerGroup.Id
                where id.HasValue ? company.Id == id : true
                select new CompanyDtoWithDetail(company, _context.AuthorizedPersons.OrderBy(person => person.Id).FirstOrDefault(person => person.CompanyId == company.Id), companyType.Name, country.Name, city.Name, district.Name, customerGroup.Name)
                      );
    }
}
```

Business Layer Update method

```cs
[ValidationAspect(typeof(CompanyValidator), Priority = 1)]
public IDataResult<Company> Update(Company entity)
{
    var check = _companyRepository.GetWithoutTracking(x => x.Id == entity.Id);
    if (check == null)
        return new ErrorDataResult<Company>(Messages.CompanyNotFound);
    _companyRepository.Update(entity);
    var result = _companyRepository.GetCompanyWithDetail(entity.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    return new SuccessDataResult<Company>(result, Messages.CompanyUpdated);
}
```

API Controller

```cs
[HttpPut("update")]
public IActionResult Update(Company company)
{
    var result = _companyService.Update(company);
    return StatusCode(result.GetStatusCode(), result);
}
```

Startup.cs

```cs
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});
// Auto Mapper Configurations
services.AddSingleton(new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
{
    mc.AddProfile(new AutoMapperBusinessProfile());
}).CreateMapper());

services.AddDbContext<Context>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Context"));
    options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
}
);

services.AddDependencyResolvers(new ICoreModule[]
{
    new CoreModule(),
});
```

```cs
public class CompanyDtoWithDetail : Company
{
    public string CompanyTypeName { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string DistrictName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerGroupName { get; set; }
    public AuthorizedPerson AuthorizedPerson { get; set; }
    public CompanyDtoWithDetail(Company company, AuthorizedPerson authorizedPerson, string companyTypeName, string countryName, string cityName, string districtName, string customerGroupName)
    {
        this.Id = company.Id;
        this.CompanyTypeId = company.CompanyTypeId;
        this.CompanyTypeName = companyTypeName;
        this.Code = company.Code;
        this.CommercialTitle = company.CommercialTitle;
        this.Explanation = company.Explanation;
        this.CountryId = company.CountryId;
        this.CountryName = countryName;
        this.CityId = company.CityId;
        this.CityName = cityName;
        this.DistrictId = company.DistrictId;
        this.DistrictName = districtName;
        this.Address = company.Address;
        this.ZipCode = company.ZipCode;
        this.CustomerGroupId = company.CustomerGroupId;
        this.CustomerGroupName = customerGroupName;
        this.IsInBlackList = company.IsInBlackList;
        this.AuthorizedPerson = authorizedPerson;
    }
}
```

```cs
[ValidationAspect(typeof(CompanyValidator), Priority = 1)]
public IDataResult<CompanyDtoWithDetail> Update(Company entity)
{
    var check = _companyRepository.GetWithoutTracking(x => x.Id == entity.Id);
    if (check == null)
        return new ErrorDataResult<CompanyDtoWithDetail>(Messages.CompanyNotFound);
    var entityState1 = _companyRepository.GetEntityState(entity); //Detached
    _companyRepository.Update(entity);
    var entityState2 = _companyRepository.GetEntityState(entity); // Unchanged
    var result = _companyRepository.GetCompanyWithDetail(entity.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    var entityState4 = _companyRepository.GetEntityState((Company)result); //Detached
    return new SuccessDataResult<CompanyDtoWithDetail>(result, Messages.CompanyUpdated);
}
```

Comment: This was a great post because the majority of the other answers were not clear to me. I am a little slow when I am tired like right now. Thanks for asking this question, most of the other ones are like 2 years plus old.

Answer (score 10):

Your entity state changes to **Modified** and then **Unchanged** when you call

```cs
_companyRepository.Update(entity);
```

See the annotated implementation here:

```cs
public void Update(T entity)
{
    var model = _context.Entry(entity);
    // state is now Modified. This supercedes the AsNoTracking()
    model.State = EntityState.Modified;
    _context.SaveChanges();
    // state is now Unchanged here; it's now part of the tracking
}
```

Then when you call

```cs
var result = _companyRepository.GetCompanyWithDetail(entity.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

you get that error because you're attempting to load another entity (the same one) into the context, where one already exists with the above **Unchanged** state.

You need to first detach the entity (set it's state to **Detached**) after the update with

```cs
context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

or you need to use a new context altogether. How you fit that into your generic repo is up to you. As it is, you are not following the typical unit of work pattern ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/)):

> A typical unit-of-work when using Entity Framework Core (EF Core) involves (my **emphasis** added):
>
> - Creation of a DbContext instance
>   -Tracking of entity instances by the context. Entities become tracked by
>
>   - Being returned from a query
>   - Being added or attached to the context
> - Changes are made to the tracked entities as needed to implement the business rule
> - **SaveChanges or SaveChangesAsync is called. EF Core detects the changes made and writes them to the database.**
> - **The DbContext instance is disposed**

When you use a `DbContext` after `SaveChanges` the context is still "live" because it's current state is still active; if you do something incompatible with that current state, such as trying to load the same entity again, you'll get errors.

**Using a DbContextFactory**

The source cited above suggests that you [use a DbContext factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor) when your scope of work does not align with the DbContext lifetime. Your case qualifies because you do work after `SaveChanges`.

**Resources**

- https://www.tektutorialshub.com/entity-framework-core/change-tracker-entity-states-in-entity-framework-core/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/

In summary, you have 3 choices

- Detach the entity after save changes and before your next read
- Use a different context from an injected factory
- Change your access pattern to not do a re-read

Comment: I have updated the question . I put GetEntityState method in EfRepository<T> class. I also shared the GetCompanyWithDetail method in repository.

Comment: in first request it is ok but in second i get error

Comment: Are you saying you get the error when you get another HTTP request, and not the first? If that's the case, I should delete my answer and flag your question as a duplicate because you are having a long-lived dbcontext, which is addressed by other questions/answers on SO.

Comment: Actually, I checked also those questions as well. I tried but i got the same error.

Comment: services.AddDbContext<ErbayWebContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Context"));
            },ServiceLifetime.Scoped
            );

Comment: services.AddDbContext<ErbayWebContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Context"));
            },ServiceLifetime.Transient
            );

Comment: Yes ı tried i detached entities after adding and update . I get the entity also by using asnotracking it worked but there has to be a short way to do that. Not as i do

Comment: I don't think there is a "short way to do that". Your Update() method sets the state to Modified, then when it actually saves, to Unchanged. That renders AsNoTracking() obviated. So now when you get the entity again, you get that error. I see no other way other than using a new context or setting entity to Detached in between update/second get.

Comment: I cannot use new context because i get it via dependency injection

Comment: Updated answer with a way around that.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. You were so thorough it made it easy for me to understand. It was easier to understand you than the docs. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score -1):

My solution:

- I removed AsNoTracking() everyhwere
- I removed setting QueryTrackingBehaviour to No Tracking
- I save entities **without** context.Update(), just modify the entity after querying, and call context.SaveChanges()

Comment: Not helpful. It's not clear why *you* had this issue and if you don't track anything, SaveChanges won't do anything. This is not a panacea.